# How to list out the categories from database with showing the product while clicking the category

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know how to display the product from the selected category. And how to do it with a limited product at that page, it can be click to next or previous to see the product within the same page.

This is the table from my database：

> ### Category
>
> category_id
>   category_name
>   category_description
>
> ### Product
>
> product_id
>   type
>   product_name
>   product_price
>   image
>   product_description
>   product_date

```
<?php
// show categories list
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$q = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from category ORDER BY category_name 
ASC");
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
echo '<li> <a href="counter.php?category_id='. $res['category_id'] 
.'">'.$res['category_name'].'</a></li>';
}
?>


<?php
    if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
    $cat_id = $_GET['category_id'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        $query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = '$cat_id' ORDER BY product_id ASC ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (!$line) echo '';
        $previd = -1;
        $currid = $line[0];
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                $previous_ids = array();
            do {
                $previous_ids[] = $line[0];
                $currid = $line[0];
                if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
                $previd = end($previous_ids);
                $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            } while ($line);
        }


        if ($previd > -1){
            echo '<a href="counter.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$previd.'" class="prev_pic"><span>Prev</span></a>';
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

            $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = '$cat_id' ORDER BY product_id ASC RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<a href="counter.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$row['id'].'"class="random">Random</a>';
            }
            echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);
            if ($line) echo '<a href="counter.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&amp;id='.$line[0].'" class="next_pic"><span>Next</span> </a><br /><br />';

                echo "</div>\\r";
            }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <form method="post" action="counter.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">

                        <div class="product">
                            <img src="img/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" style="width:100px; height:100px">
                            <h5 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="text-danger"><?php echo "RM " . $row["product_price"]; ?></h5>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?>">
                            <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="+">
                            <input type="submit" name="minus" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="-">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The expected result should be display the product when clicking the list of category. But the actual result now are not displaying the product, it is empty.

Comment: i think `product_id=` should be `category_id=` from `<a href="????">` or `$_GET['category_id']` can be `$_GET['product_id']`

Comment: `print_r($_GET);` use this line before `if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){'

Comment: and share the results

Comment: The result is **Array ( [category_id] => 15 )**

Comment: Match with the list of category_id

Comment: `SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image
FROM product
WHERE TYPE = '15'
ORDER BY product_id ASC` run this query in your phpmyadmin and share the result

Comment: any success ??? ?

Comment: I know the problem already. `"SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = '$cat_id' ORDER BY product_id ASC";`

Comment: But how to do it with a limited product at that page, it can be click to next or previous to see the product within the same page?

Answer (score 0):

to exchange

```
<a href="counter.php?product_id='. $res['category_id'] 
.'">
```

for

```
<a href="counter.php?category_id='. $res['category_id'] 
.'">
```

The get is not the same as the recovered

Comment: I changes already, still not showing those products coming out.

Comment: It only displays a list of categories but does not display any products.

Comment: Show me the data in the tables

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two issues. First, you are trying to loop over the same result set. This is not possible. Once you loop it, the way you are doing it, the results are dumped. You can use this method to return all results as an ASSOC array and then you can loop this array multiple times.

```
$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = ? ORDER BY product_id ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cat_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
...
}

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
...
}
```

Secondly, it seems like you are wanting to paginate the results of your products. You can use **LIMIT** for this. I would pass a parameter called **page** and then use this to filter the limited results. If you want 20 results per page a limit query would look like this.

```
$numPerPage = 20;
$pageNum = isset($_GET['p']) ? preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['p']) : 1;

# Get Count
$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = ? ORDER BY product_id ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cat_id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$count = array_shift($row);

$lastPage = ceil($count/$numPerPage);
if ($lastPage < 1) {
  $lastPage = 1;
}

# Check to make sure user isn't higher than set pages
if ($pageNum < 1) { 
    $pageNum = 1; 
} else if ($pageNum > $lastPage) { 
    $pageNum = $lastPage; 
}

# Get Results
$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price, image FROM product WHERE type = ? ORDER BY product_id ASC";
$limit = ' LIMIT ' .($pageNum - 1) * $numPerPage .',' .$numPerPage;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query . $limit);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cat_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
...
}

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
...
}
```

I hope this helps fix the issues you are having.